# Where to call gc.collect()

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Where should I call garbage collector? Will calling it after a function has been called clear the memory of the called function?

Also what is the difference between calling gc.collect() and specifically doing `del` on a variable

```
def a():
    b()
    # should I call gc.collect() here?
    # is there any other way to release memory allocated in the called function here?

def b():
    # big allocation like
    foo = ['abc' for x in range(10**7)]

    # should I call gc.collect() here?
    # should I do a foo = None and x = None here?
```

Comment: Why do you want to call it?

Comment: I want to call it as I am seeing that for certain functions (b) that I am calling from another function (a), on my heroku app, I get an out of memory error

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, you do not need to call `gc.collect()`.  Python collects garbage automatically from time to time, especially when it's low on memory.  What's more, calling anything when you're out of memory may not work correctly, as calling any function consumes some memory for the stack frame.

`del` does not delete objects, it deletes variables.  If multiple variables refer to the same object, `del` will only remove one of those references.  Objects are deleted when all references to them are gone (immediately), or when the only references remaining form a cycle of unreachable objects (at the next garbage collection).

If you are running out of memory, it probably means you are keeping objects alive by holding references to them longer than necessary.  Local variables are deleted automatically when they go out of scope (e.g. when a function returns), but global variables tend to live forever.  Class-level variables also tend to linger:

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = some_big_expensive_object
```

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* call it.

The garbage collector is only used to clear up circular references that are not freed by the reference counting mechanism. It will not fix your out-of-memory problem; if you have a memory leak, you should fix that.