# Python memory leakage and understanding profiler results

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, profiling

I have a set of files in numerically labelled folders and I am trying to collate and extract statistics on the included data. My minimal code is:

```python
import psutil as psutil
import sys as sys
import pandas as pd
import os as os
import glob as glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


@profile
def main():
    temp=[]
    strj=pd.DataFrame()

    ener_list=[]
    ref_ener_list=[]
    main_dir="./"
    column_list=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
    f1_list=["part1","part2"]


    for folder in sorted(glob.iglob(main_dir+"/0????")):
        print(folder)
        print(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / (1024 * 1024))
        for fld2 in sorted(glob.iglob(folder+"/run?????")):
            strj=pd.DataFrame()
            for fld1 in f1_list:
                for data_file in sorted(glob.iglob(fld2+"/prdv"+fld1+"/track.txt")):
                    temp=pd.read_table(data_file, comment="#",delim_whitespace=True,names=column_list)
                    strj=pd.concat([strj, temp])
                    del(temp)
            ener_list.append(strj.values.tolist())
            del(strj)
    print(np.shape(ener_list))

    avg_ener_list=(np.array(ener_list,dtype=object)).mean(axis=0)
    avg_ener_df=pd.DataFrame(avg_ener_list, columns=column_list)

    print(avg_ener_df,np.shape(avg_ener_df))

main()

exit()
```

For the total dataset, I have 50 folders with 1000 subfolders with 2 parts each. The size of the individual file can be either 5.6Kb(small) or 320Kb(large). When I tried running my code over all folders I noticed that I had used over 28GB memory causing the program to killed while halfway through the data extraction section. I used the memory_profiler tool to track the memory leakage but I couldn't really figure out what changes I need to make. I am inexperienced in this scenario as I haven't had to deal with memory issues before. I tried tracking memory used by variables as well but there was nothing weird there. Are there some other aspects I am overlooking here, or should I change the way I am extracting data here?

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    23   99.961 MiB   99.961 MiB           1   @profile
    24                                         def main():
    25   99.961 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       temp=[]
    26   99.961 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       strj=pd.DataFrame()
    27
    28   99.961 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       ener_list=[]
    29   99.961 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       ref_ener_list=[]
    30   99.961 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       main_dir="./"
    31   99.961 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       column_list=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
    32                                             #f_list=["part1","part2","part3"]
    33   99.961 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       f1_list=["part1","part2"]
    34   99.961 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       f2_list=["part1"]
    35
    36
    37 8065.902 MiB    0.000 MiB          10       for folder in sorted(glob.iglob(main_dir+"/0????")):
    38 7181.180 MiB    0.000 MiB           9           print(folder)
    39 7181.180 MiB    0.000 MiB           9           print(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / (1024 * 1024))
    40 8065.902 MiB   -0.527 MiB        9009           for fld2 in sorted(glob.iglob(folder+"/run?????")):
    41 8065.020 MiB   -0.527 MiB        9000               strj=pd.DataFrame()
    42 8065.133 MiB   -4.262 MiB       27000               for fld1 in f1_list:
    43 8065.133 MiB   -3.449 MiB       36000                   for data_file in sorted(glob.iglob(fld2+"/prdv"+fld1+"/track.txt")):
    44                                                             #pass
    45 8066.078 MiB 9237.312 MiB       18000                       temp=pd.read_table(data_file, comment="#",delim_whitespace=True,names=column_list)
    46 8066.078 MiB -8199.547 MiB       18000                       strj=pd.concat([strj, temp])
    47 8065.133 MiB -16399.094 MiB       18000                       del(temp)
    48                                                             #strj=pd.concat([strj, pd.read_table(data_file, comment="#",delim_whitespace=True,names=column_list)])
    49                                                         #temp.append(pd.read_csv(data_file, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=1))
    50 8065.902 MiB 6923.656 MiB        9000               ener_list.append(strj.values.tolist())
    51 8065.902 MiB   -0.270 MiB        9000               del(strj)
    52                                                 #print(sys.getsizeof(strj)/(1024*1024), sys.getsizeof(ener_list)/(1024*1024))
    53                                             #print(ener_list,np.shape(ener_list))
    54 8067.801 MiB    1.898 MiB           1       print(np.shape(ener_list))
    55
    56 8067.926 MiB    0.125 MiB           1       avg_ener_list=(np.array(ener_list,dtype=object)).mean(axis=0)
    57 8067.926 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       avg_ener_df=pd.DataFrame(avg_ener_list, columns=column_list)
    58
    59 8068.469 MiB    0.543 MiB           1       print(avg_ener_df,np.shape(avg_ener_df))
```

Comment: Using `del` on an assignment does not actually free memory - it only decrements the reference counter of the underlying object that was assigned to the name.  You may need to manually `gc.collect()`, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26761961/).  Also [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64368565/delete-and-release-memory-of-a-single-pandas-dataframe) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121659/python-del-not-freeing-all-the-memory) more relevant to pandas.

Comment: @metatoaster I tried using gc.collect() but I do not see any major changes in memory usage. Rather, my runtime for the same size dataset increases significantly and the code becomes unusable. Also in the linked threads, the main issue is that invoking gc.collect() explicitly does not usually provide any significant changes .

Comment: Well, one of the issue is that `ener_list` will continue to grow (and consume memory) as your code reads in more files, and all the `del` on the "temporary" data is unlikely to help in  your case.  Try commenting out all relevant `append` like that to see if simply processing the input files cause the issue, though if you need explicit memory management Python is not the language to use.

Comment: @metatoaster Commenting out the `append` part does remove the memory issue  and reduces the memory used to <5MiB. But weirdly the size of `ener_list` only comes out to 0.072 KiB (using getsizeof()), while psutils shows memory usage of upto 8GiB! So I am not sure where the excess memory is being utilized...

Comment: `ener_list` has a reference to something inside `strj` (via `strj.values.tolist()`), which may be have some sort of linkage to the original  which is keeping the reference count internal to numpy/pandas from being decremented?  Searching around for `tolist` memory issues I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122012/why-is-nparray-tolist-taking-this-much-space?noredirect=1&lq=1), so perhaps it is `tolist` being the culprit at leaking memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@metatoaster's suggestion was correct as `strj.values.tolist()` was the main culprit for causing memory leaks. So instead of using list of dataframes, I changed my data structure to `dict()` of `dict()` containing dataframes. My current implementation is:

```python
import sys as sys
import pandas as pd
import os as os
import glob as glob
import gc as gc
import copy
import numpy as np

def read_raw(main_dir,name,fld1,column_list):
    cm_data_list=dict()
    data_list=dict()

    for item in column_list:
        data_list[item] = []
        cm_data_list[item] = []

    for folder in sorted(glob.iglob(main_dir+"/?????")):
        print(folder)
        for fld2 in sorted(glob.iglob(folder+"/run?????")):
            strj=pd.DataFrame()
            for fld1 in f1_list:
                for data_file in sorted(glob.iglob(fld2+"/"+name+fld1+"/track.txt")):
                    temp=pd.read_table(data_file, comment="#",delim_whitespace=True,names=column_list)
                    strj=pd.concat([strj, temp])
            for item in column_list:
                data_list[item].append((strj.loc[:,item]).values)
        copy_data=copy.deepcopy(data_list)
        cm_data_list=append_dict(cm_data_list,copy_data)
        data_list=clear_dict(data_list)
  return(cm_data_list)

main_dir=os.getcwd()
column_list=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
f1_list=["part1","part2"]
print(read_raw(main_dir,"prdv",f1_list,column_list))

exit()
```

which reduced the memory consumption significantly.